# How to compile a program in wxSmith ( Codeblocks ) with all the libraries?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxpython, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I have created a program in Codeblocks (wxWidgets Application) I have compiled it and it runs perfectly when executed from the codeblocks interface ....however when i go into the release folder and run the executable it gives me *.dll file errors :/
How do i make the program ?

Comment: Can you show the actual error output?

Comment: The dll file is 'wxmsw28_gcc.dll' i get the dll file from C:\SourceCode\Libraries\wxWidgets2.8\lib\gcc_dll and paste it in the apps directory...then it shows that mingwm10.dll is missing :/ so i guess the whole folder is required :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good chance that Code:Blocks has a default setting for the executable path that includes the path to the libraries. As Windows finds the DLLs using the PATH environment variable this will ensure that your application works inside CodeBlocks.

However in order to run it outside CodeBlocks you'd need to either copy all the dependencies into the directory that holds your application or you'll have to set your PATH variable to include the directories that hold the dependencies.

Comment: How di i get it running onto the other computers ?

Comment: I can set PATH variable to include the directories that hold the dependencies....but what about running the program in other computer ?
I will need the whole library which is around 500 mb :/

Comment: Yes, you'll need to copy over all the dependencies to the other computer.

Comment: Thats just lame :/
Cause my programs around 500kb and the libs are 500 mb :/

Comment: @Rohanchrome - It's not like you're using them all though. Just copy the ones you need. This tool will list them for you: http://www.dependencywalker.com/ - Failing that, just build the app such that the libraries are statically linked, rather than dynamically linked. (exe gets larger, but depends on nothing else - no need to copy .dll/.so files)